# Combining two datasets to form a boolean column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `DataFrames` in `pandas`:

dfm_one

```
    data    group_a group_b
0   3   a   z
1   1   a   z
2   2   b   x
3   0   b   x
4   0   b   x
5   1   b   z
6   0   c   x
7   0   c   y
8   3   c   z
9   3   c   z
```

dfm_two

```
    data    group_a group_b
0   4   a   x
1   4   a   y
2   4   b   x
3   4   b   x
4   4   b   y
5   1   b   y
6   1   b   z
7   1   c   x
8   4   c   y
9   3   c   z
10  2   c   z
```

As output I want a boolean column that indicates for dfm_one whether there is a matching data entry (i.e. has the same vale) in dfm_two for each group_a group_b combination.

So my expected output is:

```
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   False
5   True
6   False
7   False
8   True
9   True
```

I'm guessing the code should look something like:

```
dfm_one.groupby(['group_a','group_b']).apply(lambda x: ??)
```

and that the function inside `apply` should make use of the `isin` method.

Another solution might be to merge the two datasets but I think this is not trivial since there is no unique identifier in the `DataFrame`.

Comment: `dfm_one.merge(dfm_two)` will give you the common values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is a slight hack, if we cast the df to `str` dtype then we can call `sum` to concatenate the rows into a string, we can use the resultant string as a kind of unique identifier and then call `isin` on the other df, again converting to a `str`:

```
In [91]:
dfm_one.astype(str).sum(axis=1).isin(dfm_two.astype(str).sum(axis=1))

Out[91]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Output from the conversions:

```
In [92]:
dfm_one.astype(str).sum(axis=1)

Out[92]:
0    3az
1    1az
2    2bx
3    0bx
4    0bx
5    1bz
6    0cx
7    0cy
8    3cz
9    3cz
dtype: object

In [93]:   
dfm_two.astype(str).sum(axis=1)

Out[93]:
0     4ax
1     4ay
2     4bx
3     4bx
4     4by
5     1by
6     1bz
7     1cx
8     4cy
9     3cz
10    2cz
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after! (But I'm guessing the string operations will make it run quite slow on my dataset with 30 mio+ rows.)

Comment: probably but calling `apply` will also be very slow as this is just a `for` loop